# Чтение и перезапись больших файлов csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Прошу совета. У меня есть большое число csv файлов с данными по котировкам (180 Гб), Вкаждом файле лежат данные за 1 день по типу ticker, цена1, цена2.
Пример: за 13082008.csv лежит:

```
A 1 2 3 4
A 2 2 2 2
A 3 4 5 6
B 1 1 1 1
B 2 3 3 3
C 1 1 1 1
C 1 1 1 1
```

Я хочу перенести данные из этих файлов в новые CSV так, чтобы у меня лежали данные по каждому тикеру. То есть по примеру у меня создадутся файлы A.csv B.csv C.csv. У меня есть решение, но оно довольно медленное, я открываю 13082008.csv, вписываю его в датафрейм, прохожусь по строкам и записываю каждую строку в нужный файл.

Не посоветуете решение, которое будет намного быстрее?

Пример моего кода:

```
def read_and_rewrite_options(path_out, folder, options):

import pandas as pd
import os
import csv   
header = ['UnderlyingSymbol', 'UnderlyingPrice', 'Exchange', 'OptionSymbol', 'OptionExt', 'Type', 'Expiration', 'DataDate', 
                  'Strike', 'Last', 'Bid', 'Ask', 'Volume', 'OpenInterest', 'IV', 'Delta', 'Gamma', 'Theta', 'Vega', 'AKA']
print('folder: ' + folder)
for ops in options:
    data = read_l2_file(path_out + folder + '/' + ops)
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        #print(row['UnderlyingSymbol'])
        path = path_in + options_folder + 'options_' + row['UnderlyingSymbol'] + '.csv'
                  # df = df.append({'symbol' : row['symbol'], 'quotedate' : row['quotedate'], 'open' : row['open'] , 'high' : row['high'], 
       #                 'low' : row['low'], 'close' : row['close'], 'volume' : row['volume'], 
       #                 'adjustedclose' : row['adjustedclose']}, ignore_index = True)
        if row['UnderlyingSymbol'] + '.csv' not in os.listdir(path_in + options_folder):    
            with open(path, 'a', newline='') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(header)
                writer.writerow(row)
        else:
             with open(path, 'a', newline='') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(row)
    print('options by ' + ops + ' are written')
print('---------------------------------------------')
```

(Тут считываю данные за месяц)

Comment: Превый столбец в приведенном датасете - это "ticker"?

Comment: Загоните данные в любую БД (дата-ticker-номер_цены-цена) или (дата-ticker-цена1-цена2-...), а потом выгрузите в требуемой форме. Чес-слово, и быстрее, и проще будет... а, может, и нафиг не нужно обратно в CSV, прямо с БД работать?

Comment: MaxU, верно, первый столбец тикер

Comment: Akina, нет возможности работать с бд

Comment: В лоб через grep не пробовали?)

Comment: eri, Подробнее?) Я новичок в питоне

Comment: без питона, без парсинга)

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется [@Akina дал очень дельный совет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1007882/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-csv#comment1708983_1007882) - можно сохранить все данные в одну SQL таблицу с индексами (`"date", "symbol"`) и далее выбирать по индексу нужные данные.

Это можно сделать приблизительно так:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from pathlib import Path

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///c:/temp/stock.db')
conn = engine.connect()

path = Path(r"/path/to/data_directory")

for f in path.glob("*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(f, ...)
    df.set_index(["Date", "Symbol"]).to_sql("stocks", conn, if_exists="append", index=True)
```

после этого вы можете читать данные следующим образом:

```
df = pd.read_sql("select * from stocks where symbol == 'AAPL'", conn)
```

PS вместо SQLite можно использовать любую БД, которую поддерживает SQL Alchemy.

---

рабочий пример с данными из `Yahoo Finance`:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///c:/temp/stocks.db')
conn = engine.connect()

f = web.DataReader(['IBM', 'GOOG', 'AAPL'], 'yahoo', '2001-01-01', '2019-01-01')
```

получим следующий датасет:

```
In [42]: f.stack()
Out[42]:
Attributes                 High          Low         Open        Close       Volume    Adj Close
Date       Symbols
2001-01-02 AAPL        1.089286     1.040179     1.062500     1.062500  113078000.0     0.930781
           IBM        87.500000    84.125000    84.500000    84.812500    8007200.0    57.459831
2001-01-03 AAPL        1.191964     1.031250     1.035714     1.169643  204268400.0     1.024641
           IBM        95.000000    83.750000    83.750000    94.625000   12769900.0    64.107704
2001-01-04 AAPL        1.321429     1.200893     1.295759     1.218750  184849000.0     1.067660
           IBM        99.750000    92.687500    94.750000    93.187500   15420500.0    63.133808
2001-01-05 AAPL        1.241071     1.147321     1.209821     1.169643  103089000.0     1.024641
...                         ...          ...          ...          ...          ...          ...
2018-12-27 IBM       113.779999   109.470001   109.989998   113.779999    6045600.0   111.149292
2018-12-28 AAPL      158.520004   154.550003   157.500000   156.229996   42291400.0   154.966034
           GOOG     1055.560059  1033.099976  1049.619995  1037.079956    1414800.0  1037.079956
           IBM       114.800003   112.500000   114.220001   113.029999    5117500.0   110.416634
2018-12-31 AAPL      159.360001   156.479996   158.529999   157.740005   35003500.0   156.463837
           GOOG     1052.699951  1023.590027  1050.959961  1035.609985    1493300.0  1035.609985
           IBM       114.349998   112.419998   113.330002   113.669998    4982800.0   111.041840
```

запишем его в SQLite DB:

```
f.stack().to_sql("stock", conn, if_exists="append", index=True)
conn.close()
```

выбираем данные по индексу из БД:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///c:/temp/stocks.db')
conn = engine.connect()

df = pd.read_sql("select * from stock where symbols == 'AAPL' and date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31'", conn)
```

результат:

```
In [46]: df
Out[46]:
                           Date Symbols        High         Low        Open       Close      Volume   Adj Close
0    2018-01-02 00:00:00.000000    AAPL  172.300003  169.259995  170.160004  172.259995  25555900.0  168.339050
1    2018-01-03 00:00:00.000000    AAPL  174.550003  171.960007  172.529999  172.229996  29517900.0  168.309738
2    2018-01-04 00:00:00.000000    AAPL  173.470001  172.080002  172.539993  173.029999  22434600.0  169.091522
3    2018-01-05 00:00:00.000000    AAPL  175.369995  173.050003  173.440002  175.000000  23660000.0  171.016678
4    2018-01-08 00:00:00.000000    AAPL  175.610001  173.929993  174.350006  174.350006  20567800.0  170.381485
5    2018-01-09 00:00:00.000000    AAPL  175.059998  173.410004  174.550003  174.330002  21584000.0  170.361954
6    2018-01-10 00:00:00.000000    AAPL  174.300003  173.000000  173.160004  174.289993  23959900.0  170.322845
..                          ...     ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...
243  2018-12-19 00:00:00.000000    AAPL  167.449997  159.089996  166.000000  160.889999  49047300.0  159.588348
244  2018-12-20 00:00:00.000000    AAPL  162.110001  155.300003  160.399994  156.830002  64773000.0  155.561188
245  2018-12-21 00:00:00.000000    AAPL  158.160004  149.630005  156.860001  150.729996  95744600.0  149.510544
246  2018-12-24 00:00:00.000000    AAPL  151.550003  146.589996  148.149994  146.830002  37169200.0  145.642090
247  2018-12-26 00:00:00.000000    AAPL  157.229996  146.720001  148.300003  157.169998  58582500.0  155.898438
248  2018-12-27 00:00:00.000000    AAPL  156.770004  150.070007  155.839996  156.149994  53117100.0  154.886688
249  2018-12-28 00:00:00.000000    AAPL  158.520004  154.550003  157.500000  156.229996  42291400.0  154.966034

[250 rows x 8 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение в лоб через grep. Бысрее наверное только в индексируемой БД:

```
grep -rh "^A" /path/with/csv/ > A.csv
```

Comment: Для windows не подойдет?

Comment: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm попробуй, только пайпы в cmd подругому

Comment: хорошо, спасибо)

Comment: можно попробовать `findstr /M ` виндовый аналог

Answer (score 1):

Я не настоящий сварщик, но если условие без использования БД, вот мой вариант фильтрации силами только `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = ['1.csv', '2.csv', ...]
    chunksize = 10 ** 6
    for file in files:
        for chunk in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=chunksize, header=None,
                                 delimiter=' ',
                                 names=['ticker', 'num1', 'num2', 'num3', 'num4']):
            tickers = chunk.ticker.unique()
            for ticker in tickers:
                target = chunk[chunk.ticker == ticker]
                target.to_csv(f'out/{ticker}.csv', mode='a',
                          header=False, index=False, sep=' ')
```

За исходный формат взят формат файла в вопросе. `chunksize` настраивается в зависимости от доступной памяти, можно и без него, если все исходные файлы небольшие по размеру. Тогда просто `chunk = pd.read_csv(...)` и дальше по коду без изменений.